# ConvLSTMCell in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

After upgrade to tensorflow version 2 from 1, all modules from tf.contrib were depreciated.

In order to apply [attention method](https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/blob/master/layers/attention.py), I need every cell's state.

Initially, what I did in tf version 1 was:

```
#ConvLSTMCell
convlstm_layer = tf.contrib.rnn.ConvLSTMCell(
                conv_ndims = 2,    
                input_shape = [10, 10, 32],
                output_channels = 32,
                kernel_shape = [2, 2],
                use_bias = True,
                skip_connection = False,
                forget_bias = 1.0,
                initializers = None,
                )


# Run RNN with ConvLSTMCell
outputs, state = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(convlstm_layer, conv1_out, time_major = False, dtype = input.dtype)
```

Now, I am trying to conver this to code in tf version 2.

However, as I mentioned above, both modules (tf.contrib and tf.compat) were depreciated.

I found the alternative of tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn which is **tf.keras.layers.rnn**

but there's no such function that creates ConvLSTMCell. Any suggestion?

Comment: Actually you can still get this cell in TF2, by either doing `from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2DCell` or `from tensorflow import keras ; from keras.layers import ConvLSTM2DCell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D?version=stable

You can import it in your code like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
conv_lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(my_parameters)
```

Comment: I see this error.    `ValueError: The RNN cell should have an attribute `state_size` (tuple of integers, one integer per RNN state).`

Comment: Well, you need to check the parameters, don't expect to copy paste all the parameters from TF1.X version and work from start.

Comment: I mean, tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D should have 'state_size' attribute to be passed into tf.keras.layers.RNN. A bunch of cell attributes is missing out in this layer to be implemented into tf.kears.layers.RNN